# How to prove that $\mathbb{P}^1_k \times \mathbb{P}^1_k$ is a normal variety?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

How can I prove that $Z=\mathbb{P}^1_k \times \mathbb{P}^1_k$ is a normal variety?

I know that a variety is normal if $\mathcal{O}_{Z,x}$ is integrally closed but I don't know how to prove this in this case.

Comment: Hint: it has an open cover by subschemes isomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^2$.

Comment: You can [click here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2467939/normal-quadric-surfaces-in-mathbbp3?rq=1)!